# Static import or plain import of a static nested class

Tags: java

I know that the traditional `import` statement is for classes and the `import static` statement is for static members. But what should you use for static nested classes?

Consider:

```
public class MyUtilityClass {
    public static class SomeNestedClass {
        //...
    }
    public static class AnotherNestedClass {
        //...
    }
}
```

With usage:

```
import MyUtilityClass.AnotherNestedClass;
import static MyUtilityClass.SomeNestedClass;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeNestedClass a = new SomeNestedClass();
        AnotherNestedClass b = new AnotherNestedClass();
    }
}
```

You see, both `import` and `import static` statements can be used. But which one is more correct, or more typical, or recommended by most coding guidelines?

Comment: In most cases we use static import for *fields* and *methods*, while plain import for *types*. So here plain import feels more *natura*l.

Comment: I don't think it is about more or less correct. It is about best practices. Static import and its corresponding variables usages are more precise and brings clarity and readability.

Comment: As a data point, the Google Java Style Guide, [3.3.4 No static import for classes](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s3.3.4-import-class-not-static) says: "Static import is not used for static nested classes. They are imported with normal imports."

Answer (score 1):

As general best practice, `static import` should be used for Members, and `import` for Classes.

From the [java documentation for `static import`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/static-import.html):

> Where the normal import declaration imports classes from packages, allowing them to be used without package qualification, the static import declaration imports static members from classes, allowing them to be used without class qualification.